# How to update a value python .ini file with configparser

Tags: python, tkinter, save, config, configparser

I am writing a code where I can put all of my other apps in(like a hub). I want to save my progress into a .ini file. I used the .set command. I also added a save write loop in the quit function, but it doesn't work. it displays this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\os\interface.py", line 20, in <module>
    apps = int(config['DEFAULT']['apps'])
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\configparser.py", line 1254, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'apps'
```

***savefile.ini***

```
[DEFAULT]
apps = blue
allapps = setings,powerbrowser
games = 0
allgames = 
coins = 0
image = 0
toolbar_color = black
```

***interface.py***

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import datetime
import calendar
import os.path
from configparser import ConfigParser
import time

root = Tk()
root.title('Gamesim')
root.geometry('1870x1080')
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('savedata/savefile.ini')

now = datetime.datetime.now()
year = now.year
month = now.month
monthes = ['None', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Augest', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
apps = int(config['DEFAULT']['apps'])
allapps = config['DEFAULT']['allapps']
games = int(config['DEFAULT']['games'])
allgames = config['DEFAULT']['allgames']
coins = int(config['DEFAULT']['coins'])
time_now = f'{monthes[month]}, {year}'
background_image = ['bg/wallpaper0.png', 'bg/wallpaper1.png']
image = int(config['DEFAULT']['image'])
toolbar_color = config['DEFAULT']['toolbar_color']
ids = []



# Functions
def quit():
    global config, root
    MsgBox1 = messagebox.askquestion('Are you sure?', 'Are you sure you want to quit?',icon = 'warning')
    if MsgBox1 == 'yes':
        with open('savedata/savefile.ini', 'w') as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)
        root.destroy()

def startapp():
    global background
    background.forget()
def closeapp():
    global background
    background.pack(expand=True)


main = Frame(root)
xmain = -2
ymain = -2

# icons
shutdown_ico = PhotoImage(file='icons/shut_down.png')

backg = PhotoImage(file=background_image[image])
background = Label(main, image=backg)
tool = Frame(background, bg=toolbar_color, width=1870, height=50)
date = Label(tool, text=time_now, fg='white', bg=toolbar_color, font='Arial 15 bold')
shutdown = Button(tool, image=shutdown_ico, bg=toolbar_color, highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT, command=quit)
border1 = Frame(tool, bg='grey', height=45, width=2)
yborder1 = 2

main.place(x=xmain, y=ymain)
tool.place(x=0, y=815)
background.pack(expand=True)
date.place(x=1370, y=10)
border1.place(x=60, y=yborder1)
shutdown.place(x=12, y=5)




root.mainloop()
```

Please help me. Maybe there is a better method.
(Im bad in English so there might be spelling mistakes).

Comment: This error doesn't seem to have anything to do with tkinter.

Comment: Yes I know, I used tkinter for the ui. The writeing seems to do the problem.

Comment: You should condense this code down to a [mcve]. If tkinter isn't required to reproduce the problem it should be stripped out of the example code.

Comment: Ok thank you I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#quick-start), usage of the code:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('savedata/savefile.ini')
apps = int(config['DEFAULT']['apps'])
```

is correct if the file being parsed through is valid. I recommend outputting the data and seeing if it parses correctly:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('savedata/savefile.ini')
print(config.sections())
```

the output should at least contain "DEFAULT". If it does not then, it's not parsing correctly, and so make sure that the filename given is valid.

Comment: Yes. I'm having a problem with changing the values. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @marksh16 if you can accept the answer to close this thread, that would be great!